# Wordpress - wrong font loadind

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a wordpress + apzo theme. No cache.

On first load on the home page (https://nursing-touch.fr/), the fonts are not correct (for instance, notice the shape of the V in word BIENVEILLANCE)
If I reload the page (F5), the fonts of the whole website are correct !

Never add this problem before, any idea of what can cause that ?

Thanx for your help.
M

Comment: load your website in incognito modus, this may be a caching problem. I dont see the issue with it. Dump cache in your browser.

Comment: This happens a lot when you're polishing the style of a web site.  Your visitors most likely won't see it.  For yourself, do <shift><refresh>  to reload the page and all its css, js, and font files.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but that's not a simple cache issue...
I tried from a new computer, new browser.
1) First loading => wrong typo
2) CRTL-F5 (need to do it 2x or 3x) => good typo

Answer (score 0):

I correct it by changing a parameter in the theme options :
typography > Google Font Display > [Optional -> Auto]

Sorry, no more explanation...